# How to add SBT Dependency to Idea Libraries?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

The question is simple:

I am using Play Framework 2.2 and want to know how it's possible that when I add a dependency to build.sbt it won't include this library automatically to the project.
I still have to manually go to the cache directory and include the jar from there and I don't think that's normal behavior, is it?

What am I doing wrong?

Procedure:

- Add dependency to build.sbt
- Run play dependencies and play update
- Open project again, dependency still not included as a library which it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating dependencies, all you need is to use `play idea` command again in your terminal. Then Idea will reload project with new dependencies.

Comment: Okay I understand this, but this is not really useful when you have distributed the project through SVN and the .idea folder is excluded (which is where the included libraries are configured). Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No, project files shouldn't contain IDE's settings, so each dev need to update his IDE himself/herself.

Comment: Keep in mind that devs may use different versions of IDE or even different IDEs, so there's no sense to commit IDE's settings to repo

Comment: Clear. Accepted as answer. Thanks.